# Jmeter is not passing the parameters in a correct manner

Tags: jmeter, parameter-passing

While running a script in JMeter, the tool is not taking the parameters in a correct way.
The "Parameter Name" is blank and the entire parameters are coming in 1 line under the "value" column due to which the script is failing.

JMeter is passing the parameters in the following way:-

### Parameter Name  ----   Value

Blank     ----------------------------              x=1&Y=2&Z=3

I want JMeter to pass the parameters in the following manner:-

### Parameter Name  ----  Value

X      ---------------------------------              1

Y     ---------------------------------               2

Z      ---------------------------------              3

Kindly suggest a way to remove the error from the script.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: share the screen shot of your HTTP Sampler.

Comment: I am not able to upload the screen shot... However the screenshot shared by Santanu is the same as that of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value and the way request has been captured seems to be correct. You will need to do a correlation of data which is being passed as parameter from the previous request.

That should resolve the error.

Possible reason of getting errors is the parameter value which you are passing is no longer valid or has changed dynamically, due to which you might be possibly getting *500 - Internal Server Error*

You must use regular expression extractor or Xpath extractor to resolve this issue.

hope this will help.